# How does the apache2 server know which config file to look into, if there are multiple config files for multiple websites in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, apache2.4

I want to host multiple websites using a single IP address i.e using name-based virtual hosting. In some of the blogs, it is given that we need to create separate config files for different websites and should enable all of them. but how does the apache server know which config file to look into? i.e if I have three config files named website1.conf,website2.conf,default.conf and if I type website2 in the chrome how does the server know which config file to look into?

Answer (score 0):

The server is compiled to look for a single configuration file, which can be overridden by the -f command line flag.  The configuration file can explicitly `Include` other configuration files or entire directories of configuration files.

At startup, the server parses the configuration. If it leads to other files, so be it. If those files have `<virtualhost>` directives, then the server will look at the directives within them to figure out what you've told it about routing requests.

`apachectl -S` can summarize what the server knows about virtual hosts.